# Submit form Ionic vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

I'm facing an issue.

I don't know why, but when I submitting my form the url is changing but not the vue.
There is my template's code :

```
<form class="space-y-4 md:space-y-6" @submit.prevent="connexion">
    <div>
        <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Email</label>
        <input v-model="email" type="email" name="email" id="email" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="name@company.com" required="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Mot de passe</label>
        <input v-model="motDePasse" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="••••••••" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" required="">
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="w-full text-white bg-primary-600 hover:bg-primary-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800">connexion</button>
</form>
```

script :

```
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/vue';
import { ref } from "vue"
import {  seConnecter } from '../../services/servicesAuth.js'
import { UserPrefsStore } from '../../store/UserPrefsStore';
import router  from '../../router/index.js'

const email = ref(''), motDePasse = ref('');


const  connexion = async function (){
    
    const userStore = UserPrefsStore()
    
    const response = await seConnecter({email,motDePasse})
    
    if(response.success){
        
        userStore.setAuthStatus(response)
        userStore.setUserInfo(response)
        
        router.push({name : "dashboard"});
    }
    
}
```

I am really trying to understand why but i'm not.
The request made by """ Seconnecter() """ is passed but the vue is not rendered.
I try to use : `router.replace()` methods but im still at the same point.
Someone have an idea about what i'm facing ?

Peraps excuse me if my english is not well.

I try to comment the part that call my localhost server and I still have the same problem